# How To Change the field on focus in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

hello sir i tried doing that but the thing is i m getting the data in array not single data ...i wanted to display the data one by one as soon as it got focus on that....here the code and result ....

```
protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time) {
        for (int i = 0; i < CrDrLabels.length; i++) {


            Field field = CrDrLabels[i];

            System.out.println("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::" + CrDrLabels[i]);

            if (field.isFocus() == true) {


                // get object for next field in focus order

                field = (i == (getFieldCount() - 1)) ? CrDrLabels(0): CrDrLabels(i + 1);

                CrDrLabels[i].setFocus();

                //break;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    private Field CrDrLabels(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

result........

```
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::KV10
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::FV6
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::HV8
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::NV12
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::OV15
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::JV9
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::DV5
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::PV16
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::Vendor1
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::New Info Systems
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::MV14
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::PV4
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::Tv23
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::Vendor4
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::Vendor5
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh::::
```

i want if focus is on any one the it should display only that data and i can perform event on that selected data ....as we r doing messaging in any phone ...

please send me some code how to sole this issue...

Answer (score 1):

This line: `field = (i == (getFieldCount() - 1)) ? CrDrLabels(0): CrDrLabels(i + 1)` has me confused because your `CrDrLabels(int)` method just returns `null`. Make sure you don't mean to use the array accessor (`[]`). Also, unless you've overriden the `toString()` method of the CrDrLabel class, you're going to be getting odd output when you `System.out.println()` it.

The easiest thing would be to just override the `onFocus()` method of your CrDrLabels to perform whatever action is needed when they gain focus.

Edit for comment:

I'll just write this as if your CrDrLabels are LabelFields. When you create them do this:

```
CrDrLabels[x] = new LabelField(theText) {
    protected void onFocus(int direction) {
        //do your work here 

        //and be sure to call super.onFocus()
        super.onFocus(direction);
    }
}
```

Comment: sir could u be more specific i m not able to understand if possible plz send me code...thanx...